# Ubuntu doesn't boot when selecting linux 3.0

Tags: 11.10, boot, kernel

I just upgraded to 11.10 from the update manager. It doesn't seem to want to boot when using the 3.0 kernel option but does with the 2.6 kernel option.

It gets stuck at the final dot of the Ubuntu bootsplash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. I upgraded to 11.10 from 11.04 on AMD64. I had to revert to the 2.6.38 kernel in order to boot properly.

I have a suggestion: Try changing

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

in the file /etc/defaults/grub

and do update-grub, and reboot. You will know why the boot fails.

In order to update the /etc/defaults/grub file. Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 at the splash screen to boot into alternative console/ environment. F1 can be replaced with F2 - F6... You will need to enter root password to proceed at this step.

I got ubuntu 11.10 with linux kernel 3.0 working. If you have an nvidia graphics card, try this. Boot into 2.6.38, and disable nouveau kernel by adding the line

```
blacklist nouveau
```

in the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

Install nvidia driver by :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current
```

Now, do an

```
update-initramfs -u -v -k 3.0.0-12-generic
```

in order to update the ramdisk for kernel 3.0, and also do

```
update-grub
```

(just in case). Now, if you try to boot into Kernel 3.0, it will work. (Worked for me...)

Comment: Its all very strange because the live cd works fine. The booting with v.3 doesn't give away any clues its just blank, theres no (fail) flag. It just stops.

Comment: I got ubuntu 11.10 with linux kernel 3.0 working. If you have an nvidia graphics card, try this. Boot into 2.6.38, and disable nouveau kernel by adding the line "blacklist nouveau" in the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. Install nvidia driver by : sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current. Now, do an update-initramfs -u -v -k 3.0.0-12-generic in order to update the ramdisk for kernel 3.0, and also do update-grub (just in case). Now, if you try to boot into Kernel 3.0, it will work. (Worked for me...)